# Statements not appearing in the terminal window java

Tags: java

This is the tester class, the terminal window only displays from the line

```
System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient3: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient3));
```

Which I mention out in the code below (scroll it down a bit to see my text) . It does not display anything above it, anyone know why?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class DayLogTest
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    DayLog today = new DayLog (11,12,1992);

    doTest(today);
}

private static void doTest (DayLog daylog)
{
    Patient patient1 = new Patient(1111, "aaaa", "aaaa", 11,11,1991);
    Patient patient2 = new Patient(2222, "bbbb", "bbbb", 9,12,1992);
    Patient patient3 = new Patient(3333, "cccc", "cccc", 8,7,1941);
    Patient patient4 = new Patient(4444, "dddd", "dddd", 4,5,1851);
    Patient patient5 = new Patient(5555, "eeee", "eeee", 1,1,1231);

    System.out.println ("Test 1");
    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println ("Phase 1: Adding Patients (patient1, patient2, patient3) ");
    daylog.addPatient (patient1, 12,30);
    daylog.addPatient (patient2, 12,40);
    daylog.addPatient (patient3, 8,40);
    System.out.println ("Number of Patients Arrived: " + daylog.getArrived());
    System.out.println ("Number of Patients Waiting: " + daylog.getNumberWaiting());
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient1: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient1));
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient2: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient2));
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient3: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient3));
    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println ("Treating patient1");
    daylog.treatPatient (patient1, 15, 30);
    System.out.println ("Number of Patients Waiting: " + daylog.getNumberWaiting());
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient2: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient2));

DOES NOT PRINT ANYTHING ABOVE HERE IN TERMINAL WINDOW
DOES NOT PRINT ANYTHING ABOVE HERE IN TERMINAL WINDOW
DOES NOT PRINT ANYTHING ABOVE HERE IN TERMINAL WINDOW


    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient3: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient3));
    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println ("Phase 2: Adding patient4 and patient 5");
    daylog.addPatient (patient4, 5,25);
    daylog.addPatient (patient5, 16,24);
    System.out.println ("Number of Patients Arrived: " + daylog.getArrived());
    System.out.println ("Number of Patients Waiting: " + daylog.getNumberWaiting());
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient2: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient2));
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient3: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient3));
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient4: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient4));
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient5: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient5));
    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println ("Treating patient 3 and 5");
    daylog.treatPatient (patient3, 11,40);
    daylog.treatPatient (patient5, 19,24);
    System.out.println ("Number of Patients Arrived: " + daylog.getArrived());
    System.out.println ("Number of Patients Waiting: " + daylog.getNumberWaiting());
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient2: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient2));
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient4: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient4));
    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println ("Phase 3: printReport method");
    daylog.printReport();
    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println ("Phase 4: printWaitingList Method");
    daylog.printWaitingList();
    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println ("Phase 5: getAverageWaitingTime Method");
    System.out.println ("I have designed the test to be 3 hours average so far, which is 180 minutes");
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("");
    System.out.println ("Average waiting time: " + fmt.format(daylog.getAverageWaitingTime()) + " minutes");
    System.out.println ("------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println ("Phase 6: Adding patient2");
    daylog.treatPatient (patient2, 20, 40);
    System.out.println ("Number of Patients Arrived: " + daylog.getArrived());
    System.out.println ("Number of Patients Waiting: " + daylog.getNumberWaiting());
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient2: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient1));
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient2: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient2));
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient3: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient3));
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient4: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient4));
    System.out.println ("Waiting position for patient5: " + daylog.findWaitingPosition (patient5));

  }
}
```

For reference if needed, DayLog Class and Patient class

```
public class DayLog
{
private Date logDate;

private int noOfArrivals = 0;

//Number of waiting patients, different from number of arrived.
private int noOfWaiting = 0;
//Number of patients being treated
private int noOfTreated = 0;

//Sets the size of the waitinglist and treatmentlist arrays
private int waitingListCapacity = 100;
private int treatmentListCapacity = 100;

//Waitlist position for the method findWaitingPosition which is one more than the index.
private int waitlistPosition;

private Patient[] waitingList;
private Patient[] treatmentList;

public DayLog (int day, int month, int year)
{
    logDate = new Date (day, month, year);

    waitingList = new Patient[waitingListCapacity];
    treatmentList = new Patient[treatmentListCapacity];
}

public void addPatient (Patient patient, int hours, int minutes)
{
    patient.setArrivalTime (hours, minutes);

    noOfArrivals++;

    for (int i = 0; i <= waitingList.length-1; i++)
    {
        if ( waitingList[i] == null )
        {
            waitingList[i] = patient;
            noOfWaiting++;
            return;
        }
    }

}

public int getArrived ()
{
    return noOfArrivals;
}

public int getNumberWaiting ()
{
    return noOfWaiting;
}

public int findWaitingPosition (Patient patient)
{
    for ( int i=0; i <= waitingList.length-1; i++)
    {
        if ( waitingList[i] == patient )
        {
            waitlistPosition = i+1;
            return waitlistPosition;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

public void treatPatient (Patient patient, int hours, int minutes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= waitingList.length-1; i++)
    {
        if (waitingList[i] == patient)
        {
            patient.setTreatmentStart (hours, minutes);
            treatmentList[noOfTreated] = patient;
            noOfTreated++;

            for (int j=i; j < noOfWaiting-1; j++ )
            {
                waitingList[j] = waitingList[j+1];
            }

            waitingList[noOfWaiting-1] = null;
            noOfWaiting--;
        }
    }

}

public void printReport ()
{
     System.out.println ("Number of patients arrived: " + noOfArrivals); 
     System.out.println ("Number of patients waiting: " + noOfWaiting ); 
     System.out.println ("Number of being treated: " + noOfTreated);


}

public void printWaitingList ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= waitingList.length-1; i++)
    {
        if ( waitingList[i] == null )
        {
        }
        else
        {
            waitingList[i].getAsString();
        }
    }

}

public void printTreatmentList ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= treatmentList.length-1; i++)
    {
        if ( treatmentList[i] == null )
        {
        }
        else
        {
            treatmentList[i].getAsString();
        }
    }
}

public double getAverageWaitingTime ()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double averageWaitingTime;
    for (int i = 0; i <= treatmentList.length-1; i++)
    {
        if ( treatmentList[i] == null )
        {
        }
        else
        {
            sum += treatmentList[i].getWaitingTime();
            count++;
        }
    }

    averageWaitingTime = (sum / count);
    return averageWaitingTime;

}
          }
```

Patient class

```
public class Patient
{
private int patientRefNo;
private String patientName;
private String patientGp;

private Date patientBirthday;

private Time patientArrivalTime;
private Time patientTreatmentTime;

public Patient (int refNo, String name, String gp, int day, int month, int year)
{
    patientRefNo = refNo;
    patientName  = name;
    patientGp    = gp;

    patientBirthday = new Date(day, month, year);

    patientArrivalTime = null;
    patientTreatmentTime = null;

}

protected void setArrivalTime (int hours, int minutes)
{
    patientArrivalTime = new Time (hours, minutes);
}

protected void setTreatmentStart (int hours, int minutes)
{
    patientTreatmentTime = new Time (hours, minutes);
}

public int getPatientNo ()
{
    return patientRefNo;
}

public String getGPName ()
{
    return patientGp;
}

public Date getDOB ()
{
    return patientBirthday;
}

public int getWaitingTime ()
{
    if ( patientArrivalTime == null || patientTreatmentTime == null )
    {

        return -1;
    }
    else
    {

        return patientTreatmentTime.getElapsedTime (patientArrivalTime);
    }
}

public String getAsString ()
{

   System.out.println ("Patient Name: " + patientName);
   System.out.println ("Patient Reference Number: " + patientRefNo);
   System.out.println ("Patient Family Doctor: " + patientGp);
   System.out.println ("Patient Birthday: " + patientBirthday.getAsString());

   if ( patientArrivalTime == null )
   {
       System.out.println ("Patient Arrival Time: this patient has not arrived yet");
   }
   else 
   {
        System.out.println ("Patient Arrival Time: " + patientArrivalTime.getAsString());
   }

   if ( patientTreatmentTime == null )
   {
       System.out.println ("Patient Treatment Time: this patient has not been treated yet");
   }
   else
   {
       System.out.println ("Patient Arrival Time: " + patientTreatmentTime.getAsString());
   }


   return "";
}




}
```

Comment: did you add these statements recently and have not build the project yet ?

Comment: Yes they were added recently, and what do you mean build the project? If you mean re-compile, yes i have. It goes wrong after Phase 5. if i delete everything after phase 5, it prints normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to test everything (because as best as I can tell, you have custom `Date` and `Time` classes not included here), but if I were to hazard a guess, is there any chance that the window *is* printing out all of these statements, but there are so many that you can't see the top ones?

It'd be quite odd if only some of the `System.out.println`'s work; try commenting out a few of the last prints, and check if you can see any of the output from before `"Waiting position for patient3"`.

Comment: Well if I print our date and time class people are gonna downvote for posting too much lines of code which already few have done. I'll try it let you know

Comment: If i comment out some lines of code it still does not display everything, but it does change what it displays. Something is interfering my code.

Comment: I found where it is going wrong, If i delete everything after phase 5 (including phase 5) it displays normally.